# Shortest path in a grid using BFS

Tags: python, graph, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

The grid consists of following items as python list of lists

```
g = [
    ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
    ['S', '1', 'X', '1', '1'],
    ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
    ['X', '1', '1', 'E', '1'],
    ['1', '1', '1', '1', 'X']
]
```

S indicates the start, E indicates the end.

1 indicates the allowed paths, X are not allowed paths

A simple BFS traversal code is

```
def find_path_bfs(s, e, grid):
    queue = list()
    path = list()
    queue.append(s)

    while len(queue) > 0:
        node = queue.pop(0)
        path.append(node)
        mark_visited(node, v)

        if node == e:
            break

        adj_nodes = get_neighbors(node, grid)
        for item in adj_nodes:
            if is_visited(item, v) is False:
                queue.append(item)

    return path
```

The algorithm, as far as I can tell is traversing correctly with the following output

```
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (0, 0), (2, 1), (0, 1), (2, 1), (0, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (0, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1), (0, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 2), (4, 1), (0, 3), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 2), (4, 1), (0, 3), (2, 4), (3, 3)]
```

Each tuple in the list represents the indices for the node in the original graph.

**How can rewrite my BFS code to return the shortest path instead of the entire traversal path followed to reach the destination node?** I have spent hours to find answers on my own but so far I have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get shortest path you should save path to current node in your queue too, so format of queue item will be:

```
(node, path_to_this_node)
```

Modified code:

```
def find_path_bfs(s, e, grid):
    queue = [(s, [])]  # start point, empty path

    while len(queue) > 0:
        node, path = queue.pop(0)
        path.append(node)
        mark_visited(node, v)

        if node == e:
            return path

        adj_nodes = get_neighbors(node, grid)
        for item in adj_nodes:
            if not is_visited(item, v):
                queue.append((item, path[:]))

    return None  # no path found
```

Comment: I am still trying to understand your solution and how it solved the problem but it did solve the issue elegantly.